# Where can I find animated textures for free?

Tags: textures, animation, water

I'm looking for some animated textures, especially water textures that show movement.

After a bit of searching, I could only find [this list](http://www.3dxo.com/textures/water). Although those textures are certainly not bad, there are only 4 to choose from. I was wondering if there is another website with free animated textures.

For static textures, I can find hundreds of websites which offer them for free, but for animated textures, websites seem to be rare.

Does anyone know of a website that offers free animated textures?

Comment: Duplicate post http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=free+sprites

Comment: Specifying "animated" means it's not an exact duplicate of any existing questions, though it may be a subset of the other question(s) on free image material (i.e. some links which are found might have already been posted on those other questions).

Comment: On second thought though... pimvdb, are you looking for animated GIFs or something? Because "animated" textures are usually in the form of sprite sheets, which the game code then animates by sequentially rendering images from the sheet. In which case, these sprite sheets might be found in previous questions.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks, but I've not been able to find what I'm looking for in the links that are posted in those posts.

Comment: @Ricket: In the end I'll need a video format, but it does not really matter - the link I provided contained a lot of images which, when put after each other, represented an animation. An animated GIF would also work, the format is not really important. I did not know about the word "sprites" so that helps in searching I think. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to glance over the content creation community portals for Second Life, as this had (and probably still has) one of the largest communities of people creating in-game objects, many of them with animated textures.

The [SL WIKI](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Main_Page) is probably a good place to start, as well as the [creators page](http://secondlife.com/destinations/howto/creator) on SL.